# Открыть запароленный zip java

Tags: java, android, zip

Использую следующий код для чтения и записи зип файла. Архив запаролен, не подскажете либу или куда вписать пароль?

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
     new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"123.zip")); 
byte[] buffer = response.body().bytes(); 
fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Надо использовать библиотеку [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/):

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("example.zip");
if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) 
    zipFile.setPassword("mypassword");
zipFile.extractAll("folder/destination");
```